# Is it possible to check the Solana program `macro` correctness before deployment?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, program

When we want to deploy program to Solana, first we need to generate the program keypair and insert the public key in my `declare_id!` macro in lib.rs.

Because I want to expose an API interface for user to upload their `.so` file & specify the expected program ID, and I'll do the uploading for them(I'll manage their keypair btw).

Just wondering if it is possible to detect if the pubkey inside `declare_id!` is equal to the expected program ID input by user before actual deployment?

So that I can tell the user that he is inserting the wrong pubkey inside his solana program.

Thanks